# less than or equal to 0 - is not showing posts which have 0 votes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a simple question and answer site, and I am trying to access the answers which votes are less than or equal to 0.

I have three answers which have no votes, but it is not showing in the `queryset`

I should show me three posts which have zero votes, but it is showing 0.

models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def answers(request):
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(likes__lte=0).count()

    context = {'answers':answers}
    return render(request, 'answers.html', context}
```

When I remove `.count()`, then it shows `<QuerySet []>`.

I have tried many times but it is still showing `0` posts which have 0 votes.

And when I set it to `lte=1`, then it shows posts which have 1 like but it doesn't show less than 0.

**Edit 1 :-**

When i tried according to below answer like :-

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(likes__level__lte=0).count()
```

Then it is keep showing

> Related Field got invalid lookup: level

Answer (score 0):

try like this bro

```
def answers(request):
   answers = Answer.objects.filter(likes__level__lte=0).count()

   context = {'answers':answers}
   return render(request, 'answers.html',context}
```

Likewise, lt for less than and gt for greater than.

for further reference  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

**EDIT**

level will be the field name in your model User.

Comment: It is showing `Related Field got invalid lookup: level`

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply what is django version?

Comment: Django Version is `3.2.6`, And Now i solved it,

Comment: oh great how you solved ? please share your answer

Comment: Can you share the `docs link` in which there is anywhere written **level lookup** ? I didn't find it anywhere in the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/) you provided in your Answer

Comment: the level should be the field in your manytomany table bro. for example if you have to filter the username from User table user__username

Comment: According to my `models.py` , i don't have a `field` named `level` which clearly means that i never knew and did about `level`, So, Did i had a dream about adding `level` field in `Model` ? btw - Please provide the working link next time and provide enough information about `Answer`, Thank You for Your Help and Time

Comment: i am really  sorry for that i forgot to add the description regards the level

Comment: No Problem, Everyone makes mistakes